# Remove Responsive Site HTML

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I  am using bootstrap for my website. But now i don't want responsive website.

Can we disable responsive site?

if yes how ?

Any ideas

Thanks  a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bootstrap [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#disable-responsive) tells you how to do this.

> 1. Omit the viewport  mentioned in the CSS docs
> 2. Override the width on the .container for each grid tier with a single width, for example width: 970px !important; Be sure that this
>      comes after the default Bootstrap CSS. You can optionally avoid the
>      !important with media queries or some selector-fu.
> 3. If using navbars, remove all navbar collapsing and expanding behavior.
> 4. For grid layouts, use .col-xs-* classes in addition to, or in place of, the medium/large ones. Don't worry, the extra-small device grid
>      scales to all resolutions.

For example, add this CSS (after the Bootstrap CSS):

```
.container {
    width: 970px !important;
}
```

And then only use `col-xs-*` classes. For example:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-xs-6"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6"></div>
</div>
```

```css
.container {
    width: 970px !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
    <div class="col-xs-6">left</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">right</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Very well explanation.

Answer (score -1):

Delete the media queries in the CSS that you no longer want to support. (Though I have to say, this is a rather odd request!)

Comment: i dint add any media queirs yet

Comment: @HituBansal if there are no media queries, then it's not really responsive.

Comment: @DA. What if you're using HTML to design a desktop application that shouldnt be responsive bu instead work on fix width?